# When I run my code in 2 player mode, the functions rounda, and roundb don't respond

Tags: javascript

When my code runs, I enter 2 player mode and call the functions, rounda, and roundb, and for some reason they don't respond. Everything else works fine but I don't know what's wrong. Thank you in advance for any possible advice. My code is below. The place where I call the functions are at the **bottom**.

```
var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 1;

var da = null;

var ga = null;

if (a === 1) {

  da = "Monday";

} else if (a === 2) {

  da = "Tuesday";

} else if (a === 3) {

  da = "Wednesday";

} else if (a === 4) {

  da = "Thursday";

} else if (a === 5) {

  da = "Friday";

} else if (a === 6) {

  da = "Saturday";

} else if (a === 7) {

  da = "Sunday";

}

var play = prompt("Please select either 1 or 2 players! Have at least 5000 credits at the end to win!");

if (play === "1") {

  var wel = confirm("On a stormy " + da + " night, lightning lurks the skies. Will you risk your business for a chance to make millions?");

} else if (play === "2") {

  confirm("On a stormy " + da + " night, lightning lurks the skies. Two electricity distributors compete head to head for dominance over the electric market. Who will reign supreme?");

} else {

  ga = 1;

}

var ezR1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2560) + 500);

var ezR2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6650) + 500);

var ezR3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6670) + 600);

var ezR4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7780) + 600);

var ezR5 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8120) + 700);

var ezR6 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9540) + 700);

var ezR7 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1230) + 800);

var ezR8 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1134) + 800);

var ezR9 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1223) + 900);

var ezR10 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1510) + 1000);

var ezR1a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2560) + 500);

var ezR2a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6650) + 500);

var ezR3a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6670) + 600);

var ezR4a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7780) + 600);

var ezR5a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8120) + 700);

var ezR6a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9540) + 700);

var ezR7a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1230) + 800);

var ezR8a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1134) + 800);

var ezR9a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1223) + 900);

var ezR10a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1510) + 1000);

var ezR1b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2560) + 500);

var ezR2b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6650) + 500);

var ezR3b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6670) + 600);

var ezR4b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7780) + 600);

var ezR5b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8120) + 700);

var ezR6b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9540) + 700);

var ezR7b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1230) + 800);

var ezR8b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1134) + 800);

var ezR9b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1223) + 900);

var ezR10b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1510) + 1000);

var choozMany = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

var chooz = Math.random();

var amountOfPower = null;

var money = null;

var moneya = null;

var moneyb = null;

var cabels = 5;

var clients = 2;

var bacout = 1;

var one = 1;

var d = 0;

var da = 0;

var db = 0;

var vas = true;

var vasa = true;

var vasb = true;

var cabelsTake = 500 * cabels;

var bacoutTake = 2000 * bacout;

var valu = "a";

var valua = "a";

var valub = "a";

var gunka = true;

var gunkb = true;

var cabelsa = 5;

var clientsa = 2;

var bacouta = 1;

var cabelsb = 5;

var clientsb = 2;

var bacoutb = 1;


function Round(x) {

  alert("Round " + x + " has begun!");

}


function s() {

  console.log(" ");

}


function Tell(a, b, c, d, z, e) {

  s();

  console.log("***********************************");

  if(e === n1 || e === n2){

  console.log("ROUND " + z + "(" + e + ")");

  } else {


   console.log("ROUND " + z);

  }



  console.log("-----------------------------------");

  console.log("Credits: " + a);

  console.log("Power Cabels: " + b);

  console.log("Back Outputters: " + c);

  console.log("Clients: " + d);

  console.log("-----------------------------------");

}


function Strike(x) {

  console.log("⚡ KABOOM! ⚡");

  console.log("Lightning strike power: " + x + " Volts");

}


function blowCable() {

  console.log("Oh No! Some of your cables have blown up! You have " + cabels + " left!");

}


function blowBacout() {

  console.log("Oh No! Some of your backup outputters have blown up! You have " + bacout + " left!");

}

// Logic(cabelsTake, bacoutTake, clients, cabels, ezRX,);

function Logic(a, b, c, d, e) {

  var total = e - a;

  var out = total - b;

  var yon = a - e;

  var cab = 500 * d;

  if (yon > 0) {

    var moneyEarned = e / 2 * c + cab;

    var result = Math.round(moneyEarned);

    money += result;

    console.log("-----------------------------------");

    console.log("Credits Earned: " + result);

    console.log("Cables/Backup Outputters Overridden: None");

    console.log("***********************************");

    s();

  } else {

    console.log(" ");

    console.log("ALERT! ALERT! Too much power!");

    console.log(" ");

    console.log("Attempting to send power to Backup Outputter... ");

    console.log("⚠️BREACH! BREACH! OUTPUTTER INVALID! ATTEMPTING TO RESEND...⚠️");

    console.log("***********************************");

    s();

    if (out < 0) {

      var pen = 3000 + cab;

      money += pen;

      console.log("***********************************");

      console.log("Success! Power diverted.");

      console.log("Credits Earned: " + pen);

      console.log("***********************************");

      s();

    } else {

      console.log("WARNING! Input to large!");

      if (chooz < 0.75 && cabels > 0) {

        cabels -= choozMany;

        blowCable();

        console.log("Cables/Backup Outputters Overridden: " + choozMany);

        console.log("***********************************");

      } else if (chooz > 0.75 && bacout > 0) {

        bacout -= choozMany;

        blowBacout();

        console.log("Cables/Backup Outputters Overridden: " + choozMany);

        console.log("***********************************");

        s();

      }

    }

  }

}

//round('round number', 'ezRX' )

function round(x, y) {

  if (d < 1 && valu === "a") {} else if (valu === "a" && vas === true) {

    alert("Press 'ok' to move on to the next round");

  }

  if (valu === "a" && money > 3000) {

    var shop = prompt("Shop Round " + x + ": 1.Power cable-$3000  2.Backup Outputter-$5000 3. Extra client-$30,000            Credits: " + "$" + money);

    if (shop === "1" && money >= 3000) {

      //cabels += one; works, money -= 1000; works

      cabels += one;

      money -= 3000;

      cabelsTake = 500 * cabels;

      bacoutTake = 2000 * bacout;

      //Round x

      Round(x);

      Tell(money, cabels, bacout, clients, x);

      Strike(y);

      Logic(cabelsTake, bacoutTake, clients, cabels, y);

      d++;

    } else if (shop === "2" && money >= 5000) {

      money -= 5000;

      cabelsTake = 500 * cabels;

      bacoutTake = 2000 * bacout;

      bacout += one;

      //Round x

      Round(x);

      Tell(money, cabels, bacout, clients, x);

      Strike(y);

      Logic(cabelsTake, bacoutTake, clients, cabels, y);

      d++;

    } else if (shop === "3" && money >= 30000) {

      money -= 30000;

      cabelsTake = 500 * cabels;

      bacoutTake = 2000 * bacout;

      clients += one;

      //Round x

      Round(x);

      Tell(money, cabels, bacout, clients, x);

      Strike(y);

      Logic(cabelsTake, bacoutTake, clients, cabels, y);

      d++;

    } else {

      var g = money / 2;

      if (money < 3000) {

        valu = "b";

      } else {

        money -= g;

        console.log("You lost " + g + " credits for skipping a turn.");

        if (money < 3000) {

          console.log("------------------");

          console.log("GAME OVER! Thanks for playing.");

          valu = "b";

          vas = false;

        }

      }

    }

    if (bacout <= 0 || cabels <= 0) {

      valu = "b";

    }

  }

  if (valu === "b" && vas === true) {

    console.log("------------------");

    console.log("GAME OVER! Thanks for playing.");

    valu = "b";

    vas = false;

  }

  if (d === 10) {

    if (money > 5000 && valu === "a") {

      console.log("Congratulations! You have made it through the storm. Your business continues to make millions!");

    } else {

      console.log("Oh No! You don't have enough money! Your business crumbles into chaos!");

    }

    valu = "b";

    vas = false;

  }

}

// Logic(cabelsTake, bacoutTake, clients, cabels, ezRX,);

//-------------------------------------------

function Logica(a, b, c, d, e) {

  var total = e - a;

  var out = total - b;

  var yon = a - e;

  var cab = 500 * d;

  if (yon > 0) {

    var moneyEarned = e / 2 * c + cab;

    var result = Math.round(moneyEarned);

    moneya += result;

    console.log("-----------------------------------");

    console.log("Credits Earned: " + result);

    console.log("Cables/Backup Outputters Overridden: None");

    console.log("***********************************");

    s();

  } else {

    console.log(" ");

    console.log("ALERT! ALERT! Too much power!");

    console.log(" ");

    console.log("Attempting to send power to Backup Outputter... ");

    console.log("⚠️BREACH! BREACH! OUTPUTTER INVALID! ATTEMPTING TO RESEND...⚠️");

    console.log("***********************************");

    s();

    if (out < 0) {

      var pen = 3000 + cab;

      moneya += pen;

      console.log("***********************************");

      console.log("Success! Power diverted.");

      console.log("Credits Earned: " + pen);

      console.log("***********************************");

      s();

    } else {

      console.log("WARNING! Input to large!");

      if (chooz < 0.75 && cabels > 0) {

        cabels -= choozMany;

        blowCable();

        console.log("Cables/Backup Outputters Overridden: " + choozMany);

        console.log("***********************************");

        s();

      } else if (chooz > 0.75 && bacout > 0) {

        bacout -= choozMany;

        blowBacout();

        console.log("Cables/Backup Outputters Overridden: " + choozMany);

        console.log("***********************************");

        s();

      }

    }

  }

}


//round('round number', 'ezRX' )

function rounda(x, y) {

  if (da < 1 && valua === "a") {} else if (valua === "a" && vasa === true && valub === true) {

    alert("Press 'ok' to move on to the next round");

  }

  if (valua === "a" && moneya > 3000 && valub === "a") {

    nexd(n1);

    var shopa = prompt("Shop Round " + x + ": 1.Power cable-$3000  2.Backup Outputter-$5000 3. Extra client-$30,000            Credits: " + "$" + moneya);

    if (shopa === "1" && moneya >= 3000) {

      //cabels += one; works, money -= 1000; works

      cabelsa += one;

      moneya -= 3000;

      cabelsTake = 500 * cabelsa;

      bacoutTake = 2000 * bacouta;

      //Round x

      Round(x);

      Tell(moneya, cabelsa, bacouta, clientsa, x, n1);

      Strike(y);

      Logica(cabelsTake, bacoutTake, clientsa, cabelsa, y);

      da++;

    } else if (shopa === "2" && moneya >= 5000) {

      moneya -= 5000;

      cabelsTake = 500 * cabelsa;

      bacoutTake = 2000 * bacouta;

      bacouta += one;

      //Round x

      Round(x);

      Tell(moneya, cabelsa, bacouta, clientsa, x, n1);

      Strike(y);

      Logica(cabelsTake, bacoutTake, clientsa, cabelsa, y);

      da++;

    } else if (shopa === "3" && moneya >= 30000) {

      moneya -= 30000;

      cabelsTake = 500 * cabelsa;

      bacoutTake = 2000 * bacouta;

      clientsa += one;

      //Round x

      Round(x);

      Tell(moneya, cabelsa, bacouta, clientsa, x, n1);

      Strike(y);

      Logica(cabelsTake, bacoutTake, clientsa, cabelsa, y);

      da++;

    } else {

      var g = moneya / 2;

      if (g < 3000 && gunka === true && gunkb === true) {

        console.log(n1 + " Eliminated!");

        console.log(n2 + " wins!");

        gunka = false;

        gunkb = false;

        valua = "b";

        valub = "b";

      } else {

        moneya -= g;

        console.log("You lost " + g + " credits for skipping a turn!");

      }

    }

  } else {}

  //Prototype

  var tosta = moneya + cabelsTake + bacoutTake + clientsa * 100;

  var tostb = moneyb + cabelsTake + bacoutTake + clientsb * 100;

  if (bacouta <= 0 || cabelsa <= 0 && gunka === true) {

    console.log(n1 + " Eliminated!");

    console.log(n2 + " wins with a total of " + tostb + " Points!");

    gunka = false;

    gunkb = false;

    valua = "b";

    valub = "b";

  }

  if (bacoutb <= 0 || cabelsb <= 0 && gunkb === true) {

    console.log(n2 + " Eliminated!");

    console.log(n1 + " wins with a total of " + tosta + " Points!");

    gunka = false;

    gunkb = false;

    valua = "b";

    valub = "b";

  }


}



//round('round number', 'ezRX' )

function roundb(x, y) {

  if (db < 1 && valub === "a") {} else if (valua === "a" && vasb === true && valub === true) {

    alert("Press 'ok' to move on to the next round");

  }

  if (valua === "a" && moneyb > 3000 && valub === "a") {

    nexd(n2);

    var shopb = prompt("Shop Round " + x + ": 1.Power cable-$3000  2.Backup Outputter-$5000 3. Extra client-$30,000            Credits: " + "$" + moneya);

    if (shopb === "1" && moneyb >= 3000) {

      //cabels += one; works, money -= 1000; works

      cabelsb += one;

      moneyb -= 3000;

      cabelsTake = 500 * cabelsb;

      bacoutTake = 2000 * bacoutb;

      //Round x

      Round(x);

      Tell(moneyb, cabelb, bacoutb, clientsb, x, n2);

      Strike(y);

      Logica(cabelsTake, bacoutTake, clientsb, cabelsb, y);

      db++;

    } else if (shopb === "2" && moneyb >= 5000) {

      moneyb -= 5000;

      cabelsTake = 500 * cabelsb;

      bacoutTake = 2000 * bacoutb;

      bacoutb += one;

      //Round x

      Round(x);

      Tell(moneyb, cabelb, bacoutb, clientsb, x, n2);

      Strike(y);

      Logica(cabelsTake, bacoutTake, clientsb, cabelsb, y);

      db++;

    } else if (shopb === "3" && moneyb >= 30000) {

      moneyb -= 30000;

      cabelsTake = 500 * cabelsb;

      bacoutTake = 2000 * bacoutb;

      clientsb += one;

      //Round x

      Round(x);

      Tell(moneyb, cabelb, bacoutb, clientsb, x, n2);

      Strike(y);

      Logica(cabelsTake, bacoutTake, clientsb, cabelsb, y);

      db++;

    } else {

      var g = moneyb / 2;

      if (g < 3000 && gunka === true && gunkb === true) {

        console.log(n2 + " Eliminated!");

        console.log(n1 + " wins!");

        gunka = false;

        gunkb = false;

        valua = "b";

        valub = "b";

      } else {

        moneyab -= g;

        console.log("You lost " + g + " credits for skipping a turn!");

      }

    }

  } else {}

  //Prototype

  var tosta = moneya + cabelsTake + bacoutTake + clientsa * 100;

  var tostb = moneyb + cabelsTake + bacoutTake + clientsb * 100;

  if (bacoutb <= 0 || cabelsb <= 0 && gunkb === true) {

    console.log(n2 + " Eliminated!");

    console.log(n1 + " wins with a total of " + tosta + " Points!");

    gunka = false;

    gunkb = false;

    valua = "b";

    valub = "b";

  }

  if (bacouta <= 0 || cabelsa <= 0 && gunka === true) {

    console.log(n1 + " Eliminated!");

    console.log(n2 + " wins with a total of " + tostb + " Points!");

    gunka = false;

    gunkb = false;

    valua = "b";

    valub = "b";

  }

  if (db === 10) {

    if (valua === "a" && valub === "a") {


        compare(tosta, tostb, n1, n2);

    } else {}

  }

}






if (play === "1") {

  //Start rounds

  money = 15000;

  round(1, ezR1);

  round(2, ezR2);

  round(3, ezR3);

  round(4, ezR4);

  round(5, ezR5);

  round(6, ezR6);

  round(7, ezR7);

  round(8, ezR8);

  round(9, ezR9);

  round(10, ezR10);

} else if (play === "2") {



var check = alert("Welcome to 2 player mode!");



    var n1 = prompt("Input Player 1's username.");

    var n2 = prompt("Input Player 2's username.");



    rounda(1, ezR1a );

    roundb(1, ezR1b );



    rounda(2, ezR2a );

    roundb(2, ezR2b );



    rounda(3, ezR3a );

    roundb(3, ezR3b );



    rounda(4, ezR4a );

    roundb(4, ezR4b );



    rounda(5, ezR5a );

    roundb(5, ezR5b );



    rounda(6, ezR6a );

    roundb(6, ezR6b );



    rounda(7, ezR7a );

    roundb(7, ezR7b );



    rounda(8, ezR8a );

    roundb(8, ezR8b );



    rounda(9, ezR9a );

    roundb(9, ezR9b );



    rounda(10, ezR10a );

    roundb(10, ezR10b );






} else {

  console.log("You didn't select a valid amount of players.");

}
```

Comment: Please try and make a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It may help you find your problem, and if not will make it far easier for people to help.

Comment: Your liberal use of whitespace kills me XD

Comment: What have you done to try to investigate your problem?

Comment: @Iguad when I have posted questions earlier, like 10 different people told me to do the opposite of what you just said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have 2 bugs

first, you're not setting values for moneya and moneyb so the 2nd if where you compare money always returns false.  and then there's the problem with not defining nexd() (lines 485, 609).

this code has way too many ifs and the variables aren't named very well.  i cleaned up the top a bit to give you some ideas

https://jsfiddle.net/ujn6uq5r/

```
var dayOfWeek = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 1,
    dateLookup = {
        1: "Monday",
        2: "Tuesday",
        3: "Wednesday",
        4: "Thursday",
        5: "Friday",
        6: "Saturday",
        7: "Sunday"
    },
    da = dateLookup[dayOfWeek],
    ga = null;
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot!